# AngularJS Cannot Set Property "PropertyName" of Null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This error is absolutely driving me crazy, and I cannot seem to fix it. I have a drop-down list that dynamically updates itself when the user selects a new option. The objects I'm working with are "Room" objects I've created, and I'm trying to make it so that when the user selects which of the available rooms should be north of the current room they are editing, the selected room's south value is set to the room being currently edited, and the room being edited's north value would be set to the selected room.

My code throws the error in my factory's addNorth function (I've tried both Room.prototype and the direct factory function) where I try to set newRoom.south = _selectedRoom

When I console.log newRoom (which is the room object that gets added as cardinalRooms.north based on my ng-model), the logged Room is a valid object which adds to my confusion.

The error thrown states: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'south' of null". I suspect it has to do with how I initialize each Room object's east, west, south, and north to null, but it's kind of important that I initialize them to null for some of my features and believe it's fairly common to do so...

Here's the relevant HTML

```
<select ng-options="n.name for n in north" ng-model="cardinalRooms.north" ng-change="updateNorth()">
    <option>
    </option>
</select>
```

Here's the relevant RoomManager factory code which handles all Room objects

```
.factory('RoomManager', function () {
    var _rooms = [];

    var _selectedRoom = {};

    var Room = function (name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.east = null;
        this.west = null;
        this.north = null;
        this.south = null;
    }

    //Add a room to the north of a given room
    Room.prototype.addNorth = function (newRoom) {
        if (this.north != null) {
            this.north.south = null;
        }
        this.north = newRoom;
        newRoom.south = this;
    }

    //Add a room to the north of a given room
    function addNorth(newRoom) {
        if (_selectedRoom.north != null) {
            _selectedRoom.north.south = null;
        }
        _selectedRoom.north = newRoom;
        newRoom.south = _selectedRoom;
    }

    //Gets all possible valid North rooms
    function getNorthRooms() {
        var northRooms = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < _rooms.length; i++) {
            //Rooms must have no south to be able to be a North room
            if (_rooms[i].south == null && _rooms[i] != _selectedRoom && _rooms[i] != _selectedRoom.east && _rooms[i] != _selectedRoom.south && _rooms[i] != _selectedRoom.west) {
                northRooms.push(_rooms[i]);
            }
        }

        return northRooms;
    }

    return {
        addNorth: addNorth,
        getNorthRooms: getNorthRooms
    }
})
```

And finally the relevant controller code

```
.controller('EditRoomCtrl', function ($scope, GameManager, RoomManager) {
    //Object for ng-model
    $scope.cardinalRooms = {};

    $scope.north = [];
    $scope.east = [];
    $scope.south = [];
    $scope.west = [];

    //Function to update room options for N, E, S, W
    $scope.updateRooms = function () {
        $scope.north = RoomManager.getNorthRooms();
        $scope.east = RoomManager.getEastRooms();
        $scope.south = RoomManager.getSouthRooms();
        $scope.west = RoomManager.getWestRooms();
    }
    //Call the function to assign init values
    $scope.updateRooms();

    $scope.updateNorth = function () {
        $scope.selectedRoom.addNorth($scope.cardinalRooms.north);
        $scope.updateRooms();
    }
    //Load rooms to room manager from selected game in game manager
    RoomManager.loadRooms(GameManager._selectedGame);

    //Assign to scope
    $scope.rooms = RoomManager.getRooms();
    $scope.selectedRoom = RoomManager.getSelectedRoom();

    //Assign values for ng-model
    $scope.cardinalRooms.north = $scope.selectedRoom.north;
    $scope.cardinalRooms.east = $scope.selectedRoom.east;
    $scope.cardinalRooms.south = $scope.selectedRoom.south;
    $scope.cardinalRooms.west = $scope.selectedRoom.west;
});
```

$scope.selectedRoom is just a variable in the RoomManager factory that gets assigned previously.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. Can certainly simplify a lot of this for example using `filter()` in `getNorthRooms()` and using utilities like `extend()`

Comment: I'd hardly call using filter() instead of typing the conditionals a simplification (because getEastRooms, getWestRooms, and getSouthRooms have slightly different requirements), and could you clarify what you mean by using extend()? I'll see if I can get a demo replicating my problem, as it is a bit confusing with all the extra fluff I have around the issue.

Comment: last 4 lines could be replaced with `angular.extend( $scope.cardinalRooms, $scope.selectedRoom)` for example

Comment: But is hard to help without a [mcve]

Comment: For my SPECIFIC issue, I've made the problem minimal (removed most, if not all, unnecessary code which was quite a lot), and the post is complete (contains all relevant code/info that is causing my error). It's hard to provide reproducible code because my project is using Ionic's framework.

Comment: No reason you can't make a testable working demo in plunker , codepen or other sandbox that we can then see the error and use dev tools to help debug with. Ionic would be irrelevant to this issue I believe